# Character encoding inside amp-bind

Tags: character-encoding, amp-html

My code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/stweyrzx/1/).
I am having issues with the `ã` character when filtering an amp-state.

I have two states, **menu** (which I cannot edit becaues is external and will come from a JSON API) and **selection** (updated with user's selection)

In the last line I want to filter the menu **state** with the two parameters that the user selects. However the `ã` character is not being recognize and is problematic. If I remove all the `ã` from **menu** state and then I filter by *Impressao* then it works. But unfortunately, the **menu** state is something I cannot change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you can use bracket notation instead of dot notion in your expression, both will pass AMP validation.

```
<p [text]="'Length of filtered Array: ' + menu.array.filter(pos =>
             pos.Tamanho == selection.Tamanho
             &&
             pos['Impressão'] == selection['Impressao']
             ).length">Length of filtered Array: ?</p>
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stweyrzx/3/).